# boost lib build configuration variations

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I am new to boost - can you please tell me what are the difference b/w
the following variations of the boost lib and which one do I need to link to in which case?

- libboost_unit_test_framework-vc80-1_35.lib
- libboost_unit_test_framework-vc80-gd-1_35.lib
- libboost_unit_test_framework-vc80-mt-1_35.lib
- libboost_unit_test_framework-vc80-mt-gd-1_35.lib
- libboost_unit_test_framework-vc80-mt-s-1_35.lib
- libboost_unit_test_framework-vc80-mt-sgd-1_35.lib
- libboost_unit_test_framework-vc80-s-1_35.lib
- libboost_unit_test_framework-vc80-sgd-1_35.lib

Well, what I actually after is to understand the whole taxonomy of the **_gd, mt, sgd** things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the link to the docs for full info on what the many suffixes means:

windows: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming

linux: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#library-naming

Although it seems it's the same anyway so either link should be good.

Answer (score 17):

```
[lib][boost_unit_test_framework]-[vc80]-[mt]-[sgd]-[1_35][.lib]
```

- `lib`: On Linux all files are prefixed with this

  - On Windows this prefix is not on "import libraries and DLLs"
- `boost_unit_test_framework`: The library name beginning with `boost_`
- `vc80`: Toolset and version used to build this library

  - `vc71`: [Microsoft Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C++) 2003 (version 7.1)
  - `vc80`: [Microsoft Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C++) 2005 (version 8.0)
  - `mgw53`: MinGW 5.3
- `mt`: Indicates multithreading support
- `sgd`: Each letter indicates something

  - `s`: Static linking
  - `g`: Linked to debug libraries
  - `y`: "using a special debug build of Python"
  - `d`: Boost debug
  - `p`: Uses "the STLPort standard library"
  - `n`: using STLPort's deprecated "native iostreams" feature
- `1_35`: Boost version
- `.lib`: Extension varies based on convention in operating system

Based on [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) (Thanks @n1ckp)

Also take a look at the list of [Boost 1.34.0 binaries available for download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.34.0/) for some examples.

Comment: nice explanation of all the options

Answer (score 8):

I use Boost on Linux, but here's what I think these are from the Linux naming.

- **mt** Multithreaded/thread-safe
- **s** Static library
- **gd** With debug symbols

On Linux **gd** seems to be just **d**, so perhaps maybe the **g** means something else in additions to "with debug symbols".

Comment: d means debug symbols, g means linked against debug standard libraries